# Visual studio 2010: no data source

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2010

I run Visual C++ Windows Forms application and MS SQL server 2005. I succeeded to connect to server and view table contents (tools -> connect to database), but when I try to add new datasource, nothing is found by wizard. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think VS 2010 does not support adding new data sources  to Visual C++ projects,but it support for c#.

Comment: After a long time of testing, asking and swearing, I verified you are right :-)